# How can I make this table scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, abstracttablemodel

I have this table here that should be displaying `Integer.MAX_VALUE` many rows with scrolling functionality, but there is no scrollpane even though I added one. Can someone shed light on what needs to be changed/added?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

class DynamicTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    final static String[] headers = {"Seconds Since Epoch", "Formatted Timestamp"};

    private static String getPrettyStringFromEpochSeconds(int seconds) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
        return formattedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return headers.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return (columnIndex == 0) ? rowIndex : getPrettyStringFromEpochSeconds(rowIndex);
    }
}

public class GoodTable extends JPanel{

    JTable jt;
    public GoodTable(){

        DynamicTableModel model = new DynamicTableModel();

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        //table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,300));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane js=new JScrollPane(table);
        js.setVisible(true);
        add(js);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        GoodTable tab= new GoodTable();
        jf.setTitle("Table");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(tab);




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation when using Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Scrolling works when I use:

```
public int getRowCount() {
    //return Integer.MAX_VALUE / 15; // doesn't work
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE / 16;
}
```

I used 16 since that is the height of each row in the table.

So the maximum preferred size would be rows * 16, since the preferred height is also limited by an Integer value.

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much for your help. 
This is unrelated, but is there a way I could use `long`s for the row and column indices instead of ints? It would be nice to be able to fit more entries before wrapping occurs, but that isn't a huge deal.

Comment: @hackingsacks, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved. The TableModel API and the JTable API uses 'Int" values. The issue is not the "int" used by the row/column. This is is the Dimension object used by Swing uses "int" values. All of Swing is designed to use "int" values. I would have no idea how to change the entire API to use "long" values. It would be an entire rewrite of the whole toolkit.